# How can I make unison stop writing itself to root root when sshing from server to server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unison

I am using this command:

```
sudo unison /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test/wp-content/uploads/ ssh://xxxx@wxxxx.cloudapp.net:7775//opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/test/wp-content/uploads -owner -group
```

upon doing so it changes this file in my .unison file path to root root.

```
sudo chown -v -R bitnami:bitnami ~/.unison/ar385a1672f0be2913a94d4d3a68db77f1
```

Because of this I have to change the ownership to bitnami bitnami and thus I can go to the other server and perform the same action.

I am trying to do a mirror master master sync setup and I need to be able to run both instructions to each sever.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you running unison as root?  Why not use `sudo -u bitnami unison` instead?  Then the file you mentioned will automatically belong to bitnami, and you have the added benefit of not exposing your server to accidental file deletions or other mishaps with root privileges.

Comment: I set the perms = 0 and now it is working... I also set it up in the user profile.  otherwise it just wasn't working correctly... Moreover, I set up my wordpress to be bitnami:daemon which helped out a lot